# Single letter string representation by '?'

Tags: ruby

I observed this in console and tried same in `irb`,

```
> ?#'a'
 => "#a" 

> ?#
 => "#" 

> ??
 => "?" 

> ?..class
 => String

> self.method('?')
# NameError (undefined method `?' for class `#<Class:#<Object:0x08ce9188>>')
```

Above works for single character while does not work for the case below

```
> ?1
 => "1" 

> ?11
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from /home/prs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
SyntaxError ((irb):33: syntax error, unexpected '?')
```

I could not find any documentation for above and could not get actual purpose of such implementation.

Please help me for proper explanation and where this can be effectively used (appreciated if example provided).

Comment: `?#` is another way to write `'#'`. Just replace it in the above code and it should become clear what's going on, i.e. `?#'a'` → `'#''a'`, `?..class` → `'.'.class`, `?11` → `'1'1` (although you get a syntax error before that) etc.

Comment: I got it cleared, thanks!

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks :) corrected!

Comment: SymbolHound is your friend for this sort of thing: http://symbolhound.com/?q=ruby+%3Fc (which of course works better when you know what you're looking for ;).

Comment: @stefan maybe a bit pedantic, but `?#` is another way to write `?"#"` not `?'#'`; it makes a difference if you're to trying something like `puts ?\t'a'`

Comment: @SimpleLime yes, you're absolutely right. My example was just for `#`, not for chars in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There is also a character literal notation to represent single character strings, which syntax is a question mark (?) followed by a single character or escape sequence that corresponds to a single codepoint in the script encoding:

```
?a       #=> "a"
?abc     #=> SyntaxError
?\n      #=> "\n"
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not go through this document, It gave explanation. I will accept this one after some time